# jquery ajax failing and not returning data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a frontend using limejs and I have this jquery AJAX call:

```
var data = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://55.55.55.55:8000/list",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    username: creds[0],
    password: creds[1]
})
data.done(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
data.fail(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

in the dev tools I can see that it was successful with a status of 200. But it always goes to `data.fail` and the value of `result` is not the json that the api returns.

Also, I can see in the **Network** tab of dev tools that the json object I wanted was returned from the GET request

Here are the response headers in **Network**

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://mywebsite.com
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:60
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 14 Aug 2015 18:35:38 GMT
ETag:W/"3c-IGO78tClmpizleUBX2+QSA"
X-Powered-By:Express`

Why doesn't it call `data.done`? and Why isn't it returning the data?

Comment: Your backend probably isn't returning JSONP.

Comment: It is cross origin so I have to do jsonp as opposed to json

Comment: What do you get in your console from `result`?

Comment: yes, inspect the data result object, what does it contain?

Comment: `Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}`

Comment: @TylerManthie815: JSONP is not magic.  Your server needs to actually serve JSONP.

Comment: alright, changing my api to serve JSONP did the trick. Sorry I don't really know anything about JSONP

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://mywebsite.com. is it really mywebsite.com that you're using? doing: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, will allow all websites to use your json result, this is called CORS